# Simple validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two textboxes, with that am trying to validate like

```
var max = $("#txtMaximumMark").val()
var min = $("#txtMinimumMark").val();

var valid = max > min;
```

if I give 10 as minimun and 100 as maximum, it shows the given value is valid, but if I give 40 as minimum and 100 as maximum, the valid returns false, whats goin on here, why it returns false, can anyone help me here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's comparing `strings`. Using `.val()` returns strings, so when you compare them, it compares them as strings.

In strings, 4 is higher than 1, so 40 is higher than 100 (like `a` is higher than `baaa`).

To do your comparison correctly, use `parseInt` to cast your strings to integers:

```
var valid = parseInt( max, 10 ) > parseInt( min, 10 );
```

Comment: It's the radix parameter. It tells `parseInt` in which base to cast. If you don't say it, `parseInt` will try to guess for you. For example, `parseInt( "09" )` casts to base 8, when you want base 10.

Answer (score 3):

compare two number you can cast to number

```
max = parseInt(max);
min = parseInt(min);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are not integers. Parse the values first:

```
var valid = parseInt( max, 10 ) > parseInt( min, 10 );
```

"40" is greater than "100". But when these are cast to integers, that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

40 > 100 if min and max instance of String.

Comment: Florian's solution is working for me, thanks for ur response FiftiN